# IMAP search for address is equal not contains

Tags: python, imap

=)

I need get all messages from email inbox with specific address.
For that i use command:

```
self.server.search(None, '(HEADER FROM "test@gmail.com")')
```

and it's work but when I try find message form `st@gmail.com` I got the same results. And I know with this criteria I searching all messages CONTAINS specific string. But for me `test@gmail.com` and `st@gmail.com` is diffrents addresses. How can I search for EQUAL not CONTAINS addresses?

```
import imaplib
self.server = imaplib.IMAP4(self.imap_ssl_host, self.imap_ssl_port)
```

Comment: What type of is `self`?

Comment: Ow my mistake. `import imaplib` `self.server = imaplib.IMAP4(self.imap_ssl_host, self.imap_ssl_port)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching for `<test@gmail.com>` instead of `test@gmail.com`.

A message from test@gmail.com usually says `From: Firstname Lastname <test@gmail.com>`, which contains the substring `<test@`, and most IMAP searches are substring searches, including `FROM`. If this hack is enough for you and whatever server you're using, good for you, otherwise you need to do clientside filtering to remove the false positives.

Comment: for my case it isn't work =(
But thanks for answer, maybe it will work for someone else